# Configuring Oracle precompiler on windows

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

Could you please help me to configure oracle precompiler on windows. I have installed oracle 11g on windows 10. Please let me know what environment variables need to be set.

Comment: Maybe this document is a manual that you might consider reading? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/win.101/a96111.pdf

Answer (score 0):

there is no environment variable to config precompiler

> $ORACLE_HOME is good for precompiler as environment variable

read [Overview of Oracle Precompilers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10839/prcmp_cll_int.htm#UNXAR183) to know more...

> Configuration file is located in **$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin/*.cfg**

- Pro*C/C++ - pcscfg.cfg
- Pro*COBOL - pcbcfg.cfg
- Pro*FORTRAN (AIX, HP-UX, and Solaris) - pccfor.cfg
- Object Type Translator - ottcfg.cfg
- SQL*Module for Ada (AIX) - pmscfg.cfg